# How to replace an IN statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

I am trying to re-write the following query (not created by myself) as this throws an execution error:

**Old Query:**

```
        SELECT LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS 'Teamleader'
        FROM dbo.EmpTable
        WHERE EmpID IN (
                SELECT SupEmpID
                FROM dbo.EmpTable
                WHERE 
                SupEmpID = (
                                SELECT EmpID 
                                FROM EmpTable 
                                WHERE SupEmpID = (
                                                SELECT EmpID 
                                                FROM EmpTable 
                                                WHERE NTID = @NTID
                                                )
                                )
                        )
        ORDER BY TeamLeader
```

I thought of using JOIN instead of the nested query but I am not sure how to apply this when there is an IN statement involved. 
So far I have the following but this is returning the same error (probably as I still have the IN statement in there).

**New Query (attempt):**

```
            SELECT      A.LastName + ', ' + A.FirstName AS TeamLeader
            FROM        dbo.EmpTable AS A
            WHERE       A.EmpID IN
                        (
                            SELECT      D.SupEmpID
                            FROM        dbo.EmpTable AS B
                            INNER JOIN  dbo.EmpTable AS C
                            ON          C.SupEmpID = B.EmpID
                            INNER JOIN  dbo.EmpTable AS C
                            ON          D.SupEmpID = C.EmpID
                            WHERE       B.NTID = @NTID
                        )
            ORDER BY TeamLeader
```

Would someone explain the IN statement here, and let me know what I could do to fix this ?

Comment: Why are you rewriting it?  Does it not give you the results you expect or do you just not like/understand it?

Comment: You can probably fix the execution error by replacing all the `= (<subquery>)` with `in (<subquery>)`.  Also, edit your question and include the actual error you are getting.

Comment: So the query throws an error, but you don't tell us the error message, so as to not confuse us with unnecessary details?

Comment: It seems you are trying to get the 3rd level parent's first name and last name by giving `NTID` of the record. if so, it can be done using `CTE`. can you share sample data and expected output of your query so that we can understand it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last query might work if you didn't have two tables aliased to `C`:

```
SELECT      A.LastName + ', ' + A.FirstName AS TeamLeader
            FROM        dbo.EmpTable AS A
            WHERE       A.EmpID IN
                        (
                            SELECT      D.SupEmpID
                            FROM        dbo.EmpTable AS B
                            INNER JOIN  dbo.EmpTable AS C
                            ON          C.SupEmpID = B.EmpID
                            INNER JOIN  dbo.EmpTable AS D
--------------------------------------------------------^
                            ON          D.SupEmpID = C.EmpID
                            WHERE       B.NTID = @NTID
                        )
            ORDER BY TeamLeader
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN` may be the best solution here.  `IN` will return all of the records from the "outer" table where there is a matching record in the inner table (or subquery).

If you did a `JOIN`, the records of the outer table would be *paired* with the records in the inner table, so you may get *multiple* results back if there are multiple matches in the inner table.  You *could* do a `DISTINCT` on the result to eliminate duplicates, but an `IN` would probably be faster since it doesn't have to match up all of the records and then eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try `LIKE` statement, because if ID is string value that will be best practise.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the obvious problem with aliases in your second query, you could use more elegant CTE:

```
;WITH ids as (
    SELECT      D.SupEmpID
    FROM        dbo.EmpTable AS B
    INNER JOIN  dbo.EmpTable AS C1 ON C1.SupEmpID = B.EmpID
    INNER JOIN  dbo.EmpTable AS C2 ON D.SupEmpID = C2.EmpID
    WHERE       B.NTID = @NTID
)
SELECT      A.LastName + ', ' + A.FirstName AS TeamLeader
FROM        dbo.EmpTable AS A
INNER JOIN ids ON ids.SupEmpID = A.EmpID
ORDER BY TeamLeader
```